# How to fetch array from helper to controller in code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to fetch array from helper to controller but it's not working for me. This is my code.

### helper/tamplate_helper.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
function tamplate_function()
{
 $navigaton_site=array("Header","Sidebar","Body","Footer");

 return $navigaton_site;
}
```

### controller/gadgets.php

```
 $this->load->helper('tamplate_helper' );
 $data['tamplate_array'] = $this->tamplate_function();
 var_dump($data);
```

Comment: try $this->load->helper('tamplate')

Comment: where i have to put that code.

Answer (score 3):

Dont use $this keyword. try-

```
 $this->load->helper('tamplate_helper' );


$data['tamplate_array'] = tamplate_function();
```

Comment: then there might be some confliction with the name of helper you are calling, please recheck!

Comment: there is not name conflicts. My helper name is unique.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it works for me:

```
$this->load->helper('template'); //You don't need the _helper string, just the name
$var = template_function();
var_dump($var); // or try print_r($var);
```

Try to modify your helper:

```
if ( ! function_exists('tamplate_function') )
{
    function tamplate_function()
    {
         $navigaton_site=array("Header","Sidebar","Body","Footer");

        return $navigaton_site;
    }

}
```

If this do not work try to get the instance with:

```
$ci = get_instance();
$ci->load->helper('template');
```

Comment: tamplate_helper is my php file. Why i dont need to include it. It is also not working. Do i need to configure something in other place to get output. Please help.

Comment: You don't need because of the docs says that you do not need it: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html

Comment: see my edit, if not works try to return a string and see if it works, if it works we will check this out

Comment: sorry i was missing $ infront ci. It is not showing error but doesnot give the output.